# How does reading and writing to same block of external flash results in bus contention?

Tags: resources, embedded

I was getting an error of bus contention when I was writing and reading to same memory area. The read and write was not simultaneous. They wait for the other process(reading/writing) to end(handled by a mutex).

When I kept a secondary area for writing, the problem got solved.

But I can not understand what happened at the background which caused the problem. Can someone help me in this regard?

Comment: Without seeing the code concerned and information on the target, it is not possible to answer your question. Is this external or on chip flash ? What is the flash part or microcontroller?  By what means have you observed "bus contention" - how was this detected and presented? Note that an erase/write operation takes a finite amount of time to complete asynchronously to the code execution, after the final write you will need to poll the ready status of the flash to be sure that it is ready for read operations - hence the need to see your code in order to assist.

Comment: @Clifford After going through the project schematic I got that the same lines are used for interfacing microcontroller with External flash and SRAM(mainly used to store display related data). This might have thrown the bus error. The error I was getting is, hardware interrupt was appearing which is named as busError in the code.

Comment: The point on all my questions in the previous comment is that you should edit the question to add the information requested so that you could get an answer. You have not provided all the information requested and that information should not be provided in the comments in any case.

Comment: The address and data bus are common to external memory devices on most platforms - that is normal.  Contention between devices is avoided by connecting the respective chip-select lines to logic with input from higher-order address lines so that only a single device can drive the data bus at a time depending on the address asserted.  It is unlikely that this is your problem - if that were the case the result would be far more catastrophic.